# error in connection mongodb atlas to shell

Tags: mongodb

> mongo "mongodb+srv://sandbox-hoj54.mongodb.net/test" --authenticationDatabase admin --username m001-student --password m001-mongodb-basics
>   2020-06-19T14:18:02.553+0530 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: SyntaxError: unexpected token: string literal :
>   @(shell):1:6

Comment: I think it will be very useful for you to go through this link https://stackoverflow.com/tour.
You need to add context, and use correct formatting tools to separate out code from response text.

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is that you are running this command:
`mongo "mongodb+srv://cluster0-jxrfu.mongodb.net/<dbname>" --username <password>` on the MongoDB shell you downloaded in your `<your mongo shell's download directory>/bin` directory.
Instead, Open up a new command line and run the command. It worked for me.
[image: mongodb connection via terminal]

Comment: before running mongo shell in cmd, add the $PATH to your environment variables.